# Text alignment changed in 2.70

Tags: interface

I am a fairly confident blender user, who has been using the software for about 1.5 years. I have recently updated from version 2.63 to version 2.70, but I have noticed that in version 2.70 the text alignment has changed.

Is there any way to change it back?

[image: Number field alignment in Blender 2.70]

I have looked all over the internet and cannot find any way to change it in the User Preferences.

Comment: I don't know of anyway to change this, short of editing the source code and compiling blender yourself.. I'm curious though, why do you prefer the old alignment over the new alignment?

Comment: That's just my personal preference - as I have used the old one for the past 1 and a half years, It looks weird to me.

Comment: Looked weird to me too at first, but I've gotten used to it. Now 2.6 looks weird!

Comment: Meh, still prefer 2.6!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a new feature in v2.70. It looks like someone missed to add it to the release notes despite this being a pretty noticeable change.

Proposal / discussion:
https://developer.blender.org/T37761

Commit:
https://developer.blender.org/rBdde5e5ce2581ffd544b442c58d6eefbc1ff61772

AFAIK there is no option to change it other than compiling without this pragma def: `USE_NUMBUTS_LR_ALIGN` (see above commit).